# Python API request authentication error when looping

Tags: python, zendesk

I'm using python to make an API request.  I'm trying to pull a list of users out of Zendesk but when I try to get more than one page of data the second page always returns as "error": "Couldn't authenticate you".  This error only comes up when I try to loop through the pages, I can pull any single page successfully.

This is the code that fails,

```
params = {'page[size]': 100}

while url:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), params=params)
    data = response.json()
    
    for user in data['users']:
        sql_statement = "insert into ..."
        cursor.execute(sql_statement)

    if data['meta']['has_more']:
        url = data['links']['next']
    else:
        url = None
```

but if I do the same thing without the while loop it succeeds on every page if I set the URL manually

```
params = {'page[size]': 100}

response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), params=params)
data = response.json()
    
for user in data['users']:
    sql_statement = "insert into ..."
    cursor.execute(sql_statement)
```

I have tried different methods of looping but the one I'm trying to make work is the one directly listed in the Zendesk documentation, an exact copy past with the only change being the SQL statement, but that part works fine.

I tried doing `print(data['links']['next'])` then just doing a copy past of that into the URL when I ran it without the loop, and it ran without issue, so its not some overarching permission issue.

I just can't figure out why it works when I manually set the page to pull but breaks when I set it up to loop.

---EDIT---
Here is the exact error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 7
      4 response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), params=params)
      5 data = response.json()
----> 7 for user in data['users']:
  8     sql_statement = "insert into ..."
  9     cursor.execute(sql_statement)

KeyError: 'users'
```

so 'users' doesn't exist in data and the contents of data is just

```
{
    "error": "Couldn't authenticate you"
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that you're making too many requests in rapid succession. Try adding a nominal `time.sleep(...)` in your while loop

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Good thought, but no go.  I tried a time.sleep(10) and it still came back with the same error.

Comment: Can you add the text of the exact error you are getting with line numbers.

Comment: @Jortega added the errors but I don't know how much it will help.  The main error is coming from some authentication error in Zendesk but it doesn't give me anything to go on.

Comment: Can you add `print(data)` right after data and see if it works the first time it goes through the loop?

Comment: @Jortega The first time through the loop does work, rather than print I had moved the sql command commit inside the loop.  I get the first 100 records in my sql table, but on the 2nd pass it fails.  If I manually change the url to start on page 2, I get the data from that page in the table, then it fails when trying to get data from page 3.

Comment: Just a guess (as we can't test this) maybe data['links']['next'] is revealing a hyperlink that you're not going to be authenticated on. I suggest printing it out. Also, might be a good idea to check that the 'users' key actually exists in the dictionary (or use *data.get('users', [])*) I'm also a big fan of testing the HTTP status code

Comment: This, `url = data['links']['next']`, I think my be the issue. I would print it out before each loop to see how its changing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Zendesk docs here, https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/introduction/rate-limits/, I will assume your url is something like this `GET /api/v2/tickets.json?page={num}` and we will add a `time.sleep(5)` to avoid the rate limit.

Based on what you said above you could try added a counter and changing the page number requested.

```
import time
params = {'page[size]': 100}
counter = 1
url = "https://EDIT_THIS.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json?page={}"

while url:
    response = requests.get(url.format(counter), auth=(user, pwd), params=params)
    counter += 1
    data = response.json()
    
    for user in data['users']:
        sql_statement = "insert into ..."
        cursor.execute(sql_statement)

    if data['meta']['has_more']:
        url = data['links']['next']
    else:
        url = None  
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: nope that didn't do it, I still get the same error in the same place.

Comment: @WhoYouExpect can you try in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more robust and add some debugging information easily which will (hopefully) lead you to understand what's wrong with your strategy.

```
import requests

user = 'user'
pwd = 'pwd'
params = {'page[size]': 100}
url = 'https://example.com'

with requests.Session() as session:
    while True:
        # print the current URL value
        print(f'GET - {url}')
        with session.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), params=params) as response:
            # check HTTP status code
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = response.json()
            # if there are no users the loop will be benign
            for user in data.get('users', []):
                print('Do SQL stuff')
            # get the 'has_more' value safely
            if data.get('meta', {}).get('has_more'):
                # get the 'next' value safely
                url = data.get('links', {}).get('next')
                if not url:
                    print('No next hyperlink')
                    break
            else:
                print('No more pages')
                break
```

Comment: this came back with

HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https:// xxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json?page%5Bafter%5D=eyJvIjoiaWQiLCJ2IjoiYVkyYk1rcGZBUUFBIn0%3D&page%5Bsize%5D=100&page%5Bsize%5D=100

Comment: Forgot to say that if I copy that exact URL and either use a browser or run it through the program outside a loop, I have no issue accessing it.

Comment: @WhoYouExpect This is no longer a Python issue *per se*. You need to review the API's requirements in terms of [probably] HTTP headers. Remember that your browser will do "clever stuff" in this respect for you. So, either check the documentation (for the API) or use your browser's development mode to determine which headers are being used then add them into your code. If you have Postman you might find that more intuitive